# dolphinscheduler tenant management and user management

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

I have deployed the Dolphin Scheduler in the background of the server and used it successfully on the front page. But there are still the following questions:

1. Tenant management questions: After I log in as an administrator, I create a tenant. Is the tenant created arbitrarily in this case? In my tests I find that the tenant must correspond to the Linux master user that is deploying the Dolphin Scheduler in the background (the user that is deploying DS). Otherwise, the workerserver task fails (user has no permission, Permission Denied), which I found in the worker-server log
2. User management question: when creating the user has the following parameters, tenants, queue, etc., the tenant here is arbitrarily chosen, but the exit administrator login to the user logs in, when performing the task flow and can choose for the user to the tenant, it is understandable for a user can correspond to multiple tenants? But you can only use one tenant at a time?
3. Queue management questions: What is the purpose of the queue here? In what way?
4. If the task stream is split and distributed to different serverworkers, if there are dependencies (e.g., task 2 needs to execute after task 1 finishes), will the two tasks be assigned simultaneously or sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

Great questions!

1. For example, I created a tenant named tony,
   When your task is executed by DolphinScheduler, the task is started in the name of tony. If the task is submitted to yarn for execution, you will see that tony is running this on the 8088 (default) ui interface of yarn Task
2. One user can correspond to multiple tenants
3. The queue name here refers to the queue on which yarn is used when your task is running, and it runs in that queue.
4. Distribute tasks according to the operating rules of DAG

if you have any questions, you also can join the DolphinScheduler Slack through invitation URL: https://s.apache.org/dolphinscheduler-slack